# Search in particular category in wordpress

Tags: php, search, categories, json, plugin-json-api

I am currently using the JSON API to get the data from wordpress

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

The plugin helps to retrieve the wordpress post data in JSON format

I notice that I can get the post within some category

```
http://www.test.com/?json=get_category_posts&id=9
```

And I can also search the post

```
http://www.test.com/?json=get_search_results&search=keywords
```

However, are there anyway to implement search within some category? Thanks

Also if JSON API is not applicable , are there other approach, I have thought of using wp_query, but do I need to provide the login info if I use the WP sdk in PHP / android?

Thanks

Comment: Concerning the alternative, are you only trying to search in a particular category? If so there is a pretty good plug in that can help you: http://codecanyon.net/item/ajax-search-pro-for-wordpress/3357410

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_posts` (Method: get_posts) which returns posts according to WordPress WP_Query parameters and then pass parameters for category and search keyword in `cat` and `s` params respectively.